# My Cordova media plugin is producing JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0 error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Im trying to play an audio file from a remote server using cordova-plugin-media but I get the following error:

**05-10 11:03:26.981: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(23184): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0**

The media plugin is as a resut not calling any of my callbacks, success or error.

What does this error mean? What could be causing it?